# How can we set an alert action for a button asking to take pictures from gallery or camera roll in swift using xib?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

```
import UIKit

class AccountViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var chooseButton: UIButton!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var myStatus: UILabel!
@IBAction func mySwitchTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    updateSwitchStatus()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateSwitchStatus()

    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = true


    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func updateSwitchStatus(){

    if mySwitch.on{

        myStatus.textColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.142, green: 0.742, blue: 0.146, alpha: 1.00)


        myStatus.text = "I'M ONLINE"

    }

    else{

        myStatus.textColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.896, green: 0.085, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.00)



        myStatus.text = "I'M OFFLINE"
    }
}
@IBAction func shootPhoto() {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
    presentViewController(imagePicker,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}

   @IBAction func btnClicked(){

    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum)){
        print("Button capture")


        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: NSDictionary) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {()-> Void in

        })

    imageView.image = image

}
```

I am using updated version of swift. `UIAlertview` does not works with iOS9 I guess. So How can I implement it?

Comment: `UIAlertView` was deprecated in iOS 8, use `UIAlertController` instead. Here is the [Class Reference from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html), and here is a [useful article from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/).

Comment: i have code for Objective C. but not for swift if you want it then i will share with you.

Comment: I need code for swift @JAGAT

Comment: This link may be helpful to you - http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/user-interaction-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller-swift

Comment: U want use alert action or UiActionSheet...?